# What does the regex [a-z]*+ mean?

Tags: php, regex

I see this in the source https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_shortcode_regex/ but in all my understand of regex, I can't explain what the + after the * quantifier does?

Comment: [Look at right top corner for explanation](https://regex101.com/r/lI7fW9/1)

Comment: Possessive Quantifiers: http://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html